# Unable to post to facebook feed through IOS sdk

Tags: ios, facebook, post, feed

I am currently having issues making a post to user's wall through facebook API.  I've requested permissions "read_stream" and "publish_stream".  I am able to log in and get the user's first name, but when I go to post nothing shows up on user's wall.  The post is made immediately after receiving user's information from call:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
```

I then attempt to make a post to user's wall with:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
@"Test", @"name",@"http://www.example.com",@"link",@"New high score!", @"caption",
                               @"Test Caption", @"description",
                               @"Test description", @"message",       
                               @"link",@"type",
                               nil];

// Publish.
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

I get a callback notification saying response was received successfully, but id of post is "0". I attached wireshark and I actually never see a post message sent over wire. I stepped through facebook code and see the post urlconnection actually made and the "connect" method called on it.  I've checked the session and it says it is still valid.  I have even tried replacing the call to get user's info with the post and still get same result.

This occurs both in simulator and device.

Any ideas on what I am missing?

Comment: Actually the posts were showing up just fine.  I was looking at the feed instead of my own posts!

Answer (score 0):

I am bit too late in answering your question,but I just came to know the fact that you are not able to post on friends wall anymore via Graph API!!

**Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API**

We will remove the ability to post to a user's friends' walls via the Graph API. Specifically, posts against [user_id]/feed where [user_id] is different from the session user, or stream.publish calls where the target_id user is different from the session user, will fail. If you want to allow people to post to their friends' timelines, invoke the feed dialog

An excerpt from the source: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/11/07/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/

I am still finding way to post with feed dialogue and will let you know if I am successful in accomplishing the task,cheers! :)